# more the 500 result row in dplyr generic SQL

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I recieve full results from any (general) SQL query in dplyr?  Here is a toy example where the SQL query simply returns the full table.

```
library("plyr")
library("dplyr")

## connect to a database
hflights_sqlite <- tbl(hflights_sqlite(), "hflights")
my_con <- src_sqlite(hflights_sqlite$src$path)

## here is the problem
tbl(my_con, sql("SELECT * FROM hflights"))
## ...
## Warning message:
## Only first 500 results retrieved. Use n = -1 to retrieve all. 
tbl(my_con, sql("SELECT * FROM hflights"), n=-1)
## ...
## Warning message:
## Only first 500 results retrieved. Use n = -1 to retrieve all.
```

(This is not a question about the particular simple SQL used here, of course)

Comment: I am not familiar with `src_sqlite`. But, the first two lines do not work for me. I tried the following `my_db <- src_sqlite(path = tempfile(), create = TRUE);my_db <- copy_to(my_db, iris)` I have the whole iris data.

Comment: @hadley Thanks.  But could you be more explicit here?  Even after reading `?collect` it is not clear to me, how to use `collect` for a general SQL query.  The obvious `collect(tbl(my_con, sql("SELECT * FROM hflights")))` is no solution.

Comment: @Andreas why is that no solution? `collect(tbl(mycol, "hflights"))` should do what you want.

Comment: @hadley Thanks.  Sorry for being unclear.  I am interested in a solution that works for any SQL query.  Not just that toy example that simply returns the whole table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `collect(n=Inf)` to force dplyr to fetch all data.

Here is an example:

`results <- CONNECTION %>% tbl(sql(SQL_QUERY)) %>% collect(n=Inf)`

where

`CONNECTION` in your case is from `src_sqlite(hflights_sqlite$src$path)`

and

`SQL_QUERY` in your case is  `"SELECT * FROM hflights"`

It looks like there used to be some bugs in setting the limit for how many would be cached, but it's been fixed: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/407

Answer (score -2):

@Andreas: If I understand `dplyr`, it's always lazy for as long as possible. When you execute the `tbl` call above, or any `tbl` call, it fetches just enough data to show you that it worked... if you want the entire resultset, you need to collect the results, per @hadley's comment, or in some other way force full evaluation, e.g.,

```
head(tbl(my_con, sql("SELECT * FROM hflights")), n=999999)
```

... `n=-1` should work, but I haven't yet seen it work properly in my testing.

Comment: Thanks for following this up.  Very much appreciated.  I would consider this a work-around as using head to collect results does not feel 'correct'.  But it does not work for me either:  `head(tbl(my_con, sql("SELECT * FROM hflights")), n=999999)
Error: limit is not an integer vector
In addition: Warning message:
Only first 500 results retrieved. Use n = -1 to retrieve all.`

Comment: Sorry... that's a bug in the current release version of dplyr, I think... try

    head(tbl(my_con, sql("SELECT * FROM hflights")), n=as.integer(999999) )

See: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/407

Comment: Also, note that collect really is the intended way to do this...

tbl(my_con, sql("SELECT * FROM hflights")) %>% collect

Comment: Thanks.  It did work all the time:  Collect does indeed return the full result set.  I was mislead by the spurious warning `Only first 500 results retrieved. Use n = -1 to retrieve all.` that is still printed.  I'll accept `collect` as answer if you put that in.

Comment: @Andreas if `collect()` doesn't work, please file a bug.

Comment: @hadley collect() does work.  It just still prints the warning about retrieving only 500 results which made me believe it does not.

Comment: @hadley bug issued.  For reference: [link](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/664)